# Suggestions to interface a photodiode in the MHz range

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, photodiode, sampling

The task at hand is to read the variations of incoming light at speeds up to 1 MHz, with some dynamic range capability (10-1000lx with 1% accuracy would suffice).

This is to be used in a device which measures lighting quality (flicker detection in light sources and backlights). Light flicker is usually in the kHz range, but we've measured an office CFL lighting that has some small 100 kHz "ripple". I take it that in order to analyze a 100 kHz signal to at least some degree, a 1 MHz sampling rate or more would be needed.

I have questions on both the analogue and the digital part of this :)

The analogue part of the question is how to interface the photodiode (SFH213). I've read that a transimpedance amplifier is the suggested path, but I need a programmable gain TIA to cater for the dynamic range. Making a TIA for a fixed gain seems doable, and there are even ICs for that, but I haven't found any programmable-gain TIA ICs (or I haven't searched well enough). Would it be a good idea to use a fixed TIA gain, tuned to the 1000lx illumination range, and then follow that with a good programmable voltage-gain amplifier to cover the 100lx and 10lx ranges? (Other ideas come to mind, but are probably stupid, e.g. a logarithmic amplifier there).

The digital part of the question is how to sample the resulting signal at 1 MHz. I've selected a dsPIC33FJ16GS502, which boasts a 4 MHz ADC sample rate. Is this actually attainable? Analyzing the signal on-the-fly would be of course impossible at 1 MHz, but I can use a sample-store-analyze approach there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot speak to the digital question, but the analog is pretty straightforward. You should use a TIA with a 1000 lux sensitivity, about 8 kohm / full scale volt. Use about a 5 volt bias, and expect a photodiode capacitance of 4 or 5 pF. I'd suggest that you don't need a PGA, rather, use a pair of x10 amplifiers in series and an analog mux to select the active channel. Be aware that selecting the appropriate channel will not be trivial in some cases, especially where there is a lot of AC on the signal. All amplifiers need to be selected with fast overload recovery in mind, or incorporate clamps. Fortunately, your currents are so low that a decent clamp should be straightforward. Log amps are in principle a good idea except that it's hard to make a good log amp that is also fast. The other problem with log amps is that it's very difficult to produce the sort of precision you want over large dynamic range.

ETA In response to a request, here's a TIA using an AD8651 and +/- 3.3 volts -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhjJLg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The AD8651 is available for less than $4 in onesies.

One thing to be careful about is the value of the feedback compensation capacitor. With the values shown, and an assumed total input capacitance of 6 pF (4 pF for the diode, 2 pF for the IC) my simulation gives settling time for a full-scale step (3 volts for 130 uA) of less than 300 nsec. However, this is quite sensitive to the value of the capacitor, and so is sensitive to layout considerations. A very compact layout is a must - which means that breadboards are absolutely verboten. Good decoupling of the +3.3 supply at the op amp is also a must - this is a 50 MHz op amp.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I'm not well experienced with this part, especially wrt "fast overload recovery" and "clamps". Why are they needed? My power rail will be at 3.3V, and using rail-to-rail opamps will make the output never exceed the Vdd of the PIC.

Comment: Think about it this way - Let's say your TIA is set up for 3 volt full scale, but the first x10 amp obviously cannot respond to more than .3 volts in (because for any more the x10 output will be more than 3 volts, right?) When the TIA out is more than .3 out, the x10 will be in overload, which means the input stage will be badly unbalanced. The point is that some op amps do not recover fast or gracefully from such conditions. Some op amp data sheets will talk about "overdrive recovery" - same thing.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies the issue. I think as long the opamp recovers gracefully, albeit slow, that wouldn't be much of an issue. Light levels will be stable (besides the flicker), and I can spend a lot of time sampling the sensor at the TIA output to determine the best amplification level to use. E.g., if the ×1 output never exceeds 0.15V, use the ×10 amp; and if THAT never exceeds 0.15V, use the ×100.

Comment: I'll have to qualify my answer some. Making a TIA with only positive supplies is going to be a problem. If there's any way to provide a negative voltage to bias the photodiode, take it.

Comment: Of course, ±3.3V rails are feasible. What specific topology you have in mind? If you could sketch a schematic, that would be great :)

Comment: Nice opamp, well except for the input C.  The spec sheet says 6 pF (diff) and 9 (common mode.).  I think it's the 6 pf that matters.. just shaking one node not both.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold - Ah. Fortunately I misspoke. It's 4 pF for the diode and 2 pF for the input leads. The simulator takes care of the intrinsic input capacitance. Also note that your answer below suggesting that 10 MHz GBW is OK doesn't work. I tried a slower op amp first. There's an old saying that "People who ask for more bandwidth than they need deserve what they get," so I started off slow. It didn't work.

Comment: Well here's the step response of a PD TIA (PD = PIN-3CD, OPA134 (8 MHz GBW) and 33 k ohm Rf.)  There a bit of gain peaking.. but it does ~ 1 MHz OK.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7bcto2q0agi4zh/TEK0034.BMP?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Getting a 1 MHz bandwidth from a reasonably sized photo-diode (PD) is not all that easy.  There's always a balance to be made.  You want lots of light, so that means a big area, but a big area means more capacitance and that limits the bandwidth.  Let me put in some numbers.   So first off let's assume room light and something like 500 lumens/ watt, so you 1000 lux is about 2 W/m^2.  A typical PD gives ~0.5A/W so that's ~1 A/m^2 or 1 uA/ mm^2.  I've got a little PD I use.  It's got an area of 3mm^2 and a capacitance of 12pf (@10 V reverse bias) and 45 pf at 0 V.  Now you would like the signal from the TIA to be greater than 100mV.  (otherwise the jonhson noise of the resistor becomes the dominate noise source.) 100mV/ 3uA is about 33 k ohm or resistance.  Let's say you have ~20 pf of input capacitance.  (PD + opamp + stray.)  that gives an RC time constant of 6.6E-7 seconds or ~250 kHz.  Hey sorry that's not that too bad... You'll need a fairly fast opamp to get to 1 MHz, but something around 8-10 MHz GBW should work.  Carry on then  (I'll leave this answer anyway.)

Comment: Oops- comment was based on a different device in a different thread. Sorry.